# node.js npm dependencies for production only

Tags: node.js, module, npm, development-environment, production-environment

Maybe I am totally off track here and I am chasing the wrong Idea:

I have node.js project which contains an npm module (let's call it my_npm_module) which I am also working on.

The module's directory is symlinked into my project like this:

```
/home
  |
  |__ myproject
  |   |
  |   |__ node_modules
  |         |__ some_other_module
  |         |__ my_npm_module (should only get installed/updated in production mode)
  |         |__ my_npm_module (symlinked only in development mode from /home/modules/mymodule)
  |
  |__modules
      |__ my_npm_module (symlinked to /home/myproject/node_modules/mymodule)
```

Now, when I call npm install/update in development mode I don't want mymodule to get installed/updated, since I want to use the symlinked version.

But I want mymodule to get installed/updated in production mode. And *only* in production (NODE_ENV=production) mode.

Since package.json "dependencies" installs/updates for either mode i.e. development *and* production and "devDependencies" installs/updates for development mode only, I am kind of stuck here.

What I am looking for is something like "productionDependencies" or at least a solution which covers this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no way to do that.

What you could do is add an extra line when you deploy.

```
$ npm install my_module 
$ NODE_ENV=production npm install
```

And when you finish with your module development ( let's say you don't want to link it anymore, because it's ready for production ), you just remove that extra line and add it to your dependencies.

Another idea is to modify your `package.json` file for production in your deploy script. This will ensure that the module will be installed only for production.

Comment: That's not exactly what I was hoping for, but you are most likely right.

Thanks for providing alternatives.